# Spyder shortcut to insert docstrings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, spyder

When I want to document my classes and functions I of course write:

```py
def function(foo):
    """
    lovely documentation 
    """
    return
```

But of course I am lazy and typing """""" then pressing the left arrow 3 times and enter is just too much for me.

Is there a hot key in Spyder that gives you """|""" where | is where the insertion cursor is

Much in the same way that pressing a left bracket in spyder immediately gives you the the right bracket with the insertion cursor between them: ( | )

If there isn't one, is it possible to make one? 
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default the opening quotes is not closed in spyder. To enable the closing quotes go to:

**Tools>Preferences>Editor>Advanced Settings** and check on *Automatic insertion of closing quotes*

[image]

Now when you enter the fourth quotation mark, you will have the quotations as you wanted it, three on the left and three on the right like this: """|""" or '''|'''

Answer (score 3):

When you type in triple quotes after a function header, an icon will pop up that says `Generate docstring`. When this happens, hit `Enter`.

Following docstring template will be generated:

```
def function (foo):
    """
    

    Parameters
    ----------
    foo : TYPE
        DESCRIPTION.

    Returns
    -------
    None.

    """
    return
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are talking about this feature:
[image]

The default hotkey is Ctrl+Alt+D